# How to enable Cross Domains in ASP.NET Web api + Angular

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain

my project is : ASP.NET Web Api C# With Angular

i am trying to make simple http get with allow cross domains from angular client

the request :

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Key'] = 'somekey';
$http.defaults.headers.common['X-Auth-Email'] = 'someuser';
$http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
$http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
return {
    GetDomains: function () {
      return  $http({
          method: "get",
          url: "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/cd7d068de3012345da9420df9514dad0/dns_records?page=3&per_page=20&order=type&direction=asc",
          responseType: 'json'
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            return response.data;
        })
    }
}
});
```

in the response i can see :

access-control-request-headers:access-control-allow-methods, access-control- allow-origin, x-auth-email, x-auth-key

and the error :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/cd7d068de3012345da9420df9514dad0/dns_records?page=3&per_page=20&order=type&direction=asc. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

i am trying to do it with iis express with visual studio 2015

IIS Express applicationhost.config and Web.Config files have :

```
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="X-Powered-By" value="ASP.NET" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Accept, X-Access-Token, X-Application-Name, X-Request-Sent-Time"/>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
        </customHeaders>
        <redirectHeaders>
            <clear />
        </redirectHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

App_Start / WebApiConfig.cs file :

```
         var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("https://api.cloudflare.com", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```

and still the same error

i tried everything
may be you can help me

thank you !

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable CORS in your WebApi Backend as described in this article:

[Enabling Cors](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

The necessary parts are to install the package for cors with this commamd:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Then adding the needed methods to your Startup/WebConfig

```
using System.Web.Http;
namespace WebService
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // New code
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And after that you need to enable Cors either application wide or specific for your controllers:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // Controller methods not shown...
}
```

To enable CORS globally you need to create a Cors Config as shown in this example:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("www.example.com", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: sorry forgot to add it but i already configured EnableCors globaly

see my update

Comment: Have you added this attribute exactly that way you wrote or is this a Typo? Because if the domain that needs to be enabled is _api.cloudflare.com_ and you want to enable it on all requests from this site you need to write `config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("api.cloudflare.com", "*", "*");   `. If you forgot the wildcards you won´t be able to connect. Also, from the question you wrote I think, that your origin is _http://localhost_ so you at least have to enable this as allowed CORS Origin too, because the Origin is the address from the calling client.

Comment: Wow dude, this totally fixed my CORS issue. Thank you!